# Prevent reloading the page after clicking on submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add items in cart for which I am using forms for submission. I cant see and console.log messages as it is reloading when I click on submit.

Below, I have pasted my HTML and JS. I know this error is caused mainly due to `event.preventDefault` yet I am failing to fix this.

HTML

```
    <main id="container">
        <div id="items-div">
            <form id="form-data">
                <div id="table-div">
                    <table id="table-form">
                        <tr class="rows">
                            <td class="labels-col" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                                <label for="name" >Name</label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="inputs-col">
                                <input name="name"
                                id="cusName"
                                type="text" 
                                class="input-class"
                                placeholder="James">
                                <small class="error" id="name-error"></small>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                    
                        <tr class="rows">
                            <td class="labels-col">
                                <label for="num">Phone Number</label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="inputs-col">
                                <input name="num"
                                id="cusNum" 
                                type="text" 
                                class="input-class" 
                                placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx">
                                <small class="error" id="number-error"></small>
                            </td>
                        </tr>      
                    </table> 
                </div>                   
                <h2 id="h2">Items Available for Purchase</h2>
                <div id="items-div">
                    
                    <div id="item-cap" class="item-div-class">               
                        <img id="cap-img" src="../images/cap.jpg" alt="broken_logo" class="jpg-img">                
                        <h3>Cap</h3>
                        <em>$10.00</em> 
                        <div class="content">
                            <input name="cap" type="text" id="cap-quant" placeholder="1 to 100">
                        </div>                              
                    </div>

                    <div id="item-shirt" class="item-div-class">               
                        <img id="shirt-img" src="../images/shirt.jpg" alt="broken_logo" class="jpg-img">                
                        <h3>T-Shirt</h3>
                        <em>$15.00</em> 
                        <div class="content">
                            <input name="shirt" type="text" id="shirt-quant" placeholder="1 to 100">
                        </div>                                                      
                    </div>

                    <div id="item-jacket" class="item-div-class">              
                        <img id="jacket-img" src="../images/jacket.jpg" alt="broken_logo" class="jpg-img">                
                        <h3>Jacket</h3>
                        <em>$50.00</em>       
                        <div class="content">
                            <input name="jacket" type="text" id="jacket-quant" placeholder="1 to 100">
                        </div>                       
                    </div>

                    <div id="item-glasses" class="item-div-class">                
                        <img id="glasses-img" src="../images/glasses.jpg" alt="broken_logo" class="jpg-img">                
                        <h3>Sunglasses</h3>
                        <em>$35.00</em>    
                        <div class="content">
                            <input name="glass" type="text" id="glass-quant" placeholder="1 to 100">
                        </div>          
                    </div>

                    <div id="item-bracelet" class="item-div-class">              
                        <img id="bracelet-img" src="../images/bracelet.jpg" alt="broken_logo" class="jpg-img">                
                        <h3>Bracelet</h3>
                        <em>$25</em>      
                        <div class="content">
                            <input name="brace" type="text" id="brace-quant" placeholder="1 to 100">
                        </div> 
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div id="error">
                    <small id="none-selected">Please add atleast <strong>ONE ITEM</strong> to cart.</small>
                    <br>
                    <small id="invalid-input">Item quantity should <strong>ONLY be POSITIVE</strong> numbers</small>
                </div>
                
                <button type="submit" id="checkout-btn">Checkout</button>
                <!-- <input type="submit" value="Checkout" id="checkout-btn"> -->
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>

        
    <script src="../script/ShopPageScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const nameErr = document.getElementById("name-error"),
 numErr = document.getElementById("number-error")

// get elements to display error
const noneSelected = document.getElementById("none-selected"),
 invalidInput = document.getElementById("invalid-input")

 // hide error messeges
noneSelected.style.visibility = "hidden"
invalidInput.style.visibility = "hidden"

const form = document.getElementById('form-data');

const checkout = document.getElementById('checkout-btn');

checkout.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    checkoutItems()   
});
```

In above code, when I am submitting the form, my page is reloading.
What should I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

You should attach the event listener to the form itself, not the button:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
```

```js
const nameErr = document.getElementById("name-error"),
 numErr = document.getElementById("number-error")

// get elements to display error
const noneSelected = document.getElementById("none-selected"),
 invalidInput = document.getElementById("invalid-input")

 // hide error messeges
noneSelected.style.visibility = "hidden"
invalidInput.style.visibility = "hidden"

const form = document.getElementById('form-data');

const checkout = document.getElementById('checkout-btn');

form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //checkoutItems();   
});
```

```html
<main id="container">
  <div id="items-div">
      <form id="form-data">
          <div id="table-div">
              <table id="table-form">
                  <tr class="rows">
                      <td class="labels-col" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                          <label for="name" >Name</label>
                      </td>
                      <td class="inputs-col">
                          <input name="name"
                          id="cusName"
                          type="text" 
                          class="input-class"
                          placeholder="James">
                          <small class="error" id="name-error"></small>
                      </td>
                  </tr>                    
                  <tr class="rows">
                      <td class="labels-col">
                          <label for="num">Phone Number</label>
                      </td>
                      <td class="inputs-col">
                          <input name="num"
                          id="cusNum" 
                          type="text" 
                          class="input-class" 
                          placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx">
                          <small class="error" id="number-error"></small>
                      </td>
                  </tr>      
              </table> 
          </div>                   
          <h2 id="h2">Items Available for Purchase</h2>
          <div id="items-div">

              <div id="item-cap" class="item-div-class">               
                  <img id="cap-img" src="../images/cap.jpg" alt="broken_logo" class="jpg-img">                
                  <h3>Cap</h3>
                  <em>$10.00</em> 
                  <div class="content">
                      <input name="cap" type="text" id="cap-quant" placeholder="1 to 100">
                  </div>                              
              </div>

              <div id="item-shirt" class="item-div-class">               
                  <img id="shirt-img" src="../images/shirt.jpg" alt="broken_logo" class="jpg-img">                
                  <h3>T-Shirt</h3>
                  <em>$15.00</em> 
                  <div class="content">
                      <input name="shirt" type="text" id="shirt-quant" placeholder="1 to 100">
                  </div>                                                      
              </div>

              <div id="item-jacket" class="item-div-class">              
                  <img id="jacket-img" src="../images/jacket.jpg" alt="broken_logo" class="jpg-img">                
                  <h3>Jacket</h3>
                  <em>$50.00</em>       
                  <div class="content">
                      <input name="jacket" type="text" id="jacket-quant" placeholder="1 to 100">
                  </div>                       
              </div>

              <div id="item-glasses" class="item-div-class">                
                  <img id="glasses-img" src="../images/glasses.jpg" alt="broken_logo" class="jpg-img">                
                  <h3>Sunglasses</h3>
                  <em>$35.00</em>    
                  <div class="content">
                      <input name="glass" type="text" id="glass-quant" placeholder="1 to 100">
                  </div>          
              </div>

              <div id="item-bracelet" class="item-div-class">              
                  <img id="bracelet-img" src="../images/bracelet.jpg" alt="broken_logo" class="jpg-img">                
                  <h3>Bracelet</h3>
                  <em>$25</em>      
                  <div class="content">
                      <input name="brace" type="text" id="brace-quant" placeholder="1 to 100">
                  </div> 
              </div>  
          </div>
          <div id="error">
              <small id="none-selected">Please add atleast <strong>ONE ITEM</strong> to cart.</small>
              <br>
              <small id="invalid-input">Item quantity should <strong>ONLY be POSITIVE</strong> numbers</small>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" id="checkout-btn">Checkout</button>
          <!-- <input type="submit" value="Checkout" id="checkout-btn"> -->
      </form>
  </div>
</main>
```